# URL encodin in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Previously I had url as below:

```
http://xyz.in/Modules/kOPYWOeJHOjPM04ejG%2faRA%3d%3d
```

and it used to give me error saying resource not found (because %2f in url, it is getting decoded by MVC), but when I do it like below:

```
http://xyz.in/Modules/id=kOPYWOeJHOjPM04ejG%2faRA%3d%3d
```

(added id= before parameter value) then it works fine.

I want url to work without mentioning id (parameter name). Can I even achieve it?

**Update:**

Routing rule is as below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Modules",
    url: "Modules/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Modules", action = "Modules", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and controller code:

```
public class ModulesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Modules(string id)
    {
        var topic = new Topic();
        return View("Modules", topic.GetTopicWithModules(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(id)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, show us the route configuration and the action method on your controller.

Comment: I assume that you are facing the issue regarding the  routing rules defined in RouteConfig.cs. You can achieve tour desired result if you could define a new specific route. Could u please provide some of your codes

Comment: @Amy I have updated my question as sugested, thanks.

Comment: @MahyarMottaghiZadeh  I have updated my question as sugested, thanks.

Comment: `defaults: new { controller = "Modules", action = "Modules", id = UrlParameter.Optional }` --> your mapping is for an ACTION called Module, but your controller action you seem to expect to hit is Topics. I assume you meant `defaults: new { controller = "Modules", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }` with an Index action.

Comment: @Imad did you check the issue with the url not containing %2f ?

Comment: @MahyarMottaghiZadeh Yes I did, and it works fine

Comment: So cant you create a custom convention in order to prevent the creation of %2f?

Comment: @MahyarMottaghiZadeh That would dangerous I guess because this string is a result of encryption and it would break sometime for sure.